# how to insert sound to this code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

hello how to put sounds to this code so when tower firing bullet sound will show up together with it...i'm just nubie so i really need a help
can you help me how to put sounds in this code

this is the code

```js
package Game
    {
     import flash.display.MovieClip;
     import flash.events.*;
     import flash.geom.*; 
     import Gamess.BulletThree;
     import Games.BulletTwo;
     
     public class Tower_Fire extends MovieClip
     {  
      private var isActive:Boolean;
      private var range,cooldown,damage:Number;
      
      public function Tower_Fire()
      {
       isActive = false;
       range = C.TOWER_FIRE_RANGE;
       cooldown = C.TOWER_FIRE_COOLDOWN;
       damage = C.TOWER_FIRE_DAMAGE;
       this.mouseEnabled = false;
      }
      
      public function setActive()
      {
       isActive = true;
      }
      
      public function update()
      {
       if (isActive)
       {
        var monsters = GameController(root).monsters;
        if (cooldown <= 0)
        {
         for (var j = 0; j < monsters.length; j++)
         {
          var currMonster = monsters[j];
          
          if ((Math.pow((currMonster.x - this.x),2) 
           + Math.pow((currMonster.y - this.y),2)) < this.range)
          {
           //spawn new bullet
           var bulletRotation = (180/Math.PI)*
              Math.atan2((currMonster.y - this.y), 
                (currMonster.x - this.x));
           var newBullet = new Bullet(currMonster.x,currMonster.y,
              "fire",currMonster,this.damage,bulletRotation);
           newBullet.x = this.x;
           newBullet.y = this.y;
           
           GameController(root).bullets.push(newBullet);
                 GameController(root).mcGameStage.addChild(newBullet);
           
           this.cooldown = C.TOWER_FIRE_COOLDOWN;
           
           break;
          }
         }
        }
        else
        {
         this.cooldown -= 1;
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to export sound for AS:[image]

and then you can play sound from code:

```
var sound:Sound = new Track();
sound.play();
```

UPDATE:

```
if ((Math.pow((currMonster.x - this.x),2) + Math.pow((currMonster.y - this.y),2)) < this.range)
{
    //spawn new bullet

    var sound:Sound = new Track();
    sound.play();

    var bulletRotation = (180/Math.PI)*
    Math.atan2((currMonster.y - this.y), (currMonster.x - this.x));
    ...
```

Comment: ok sir got it...so where should i insert that code? i mean to make it work when the tower firing bullet sounds will came up..where should i wrote that code?